# iOS Mail App For Android

Tags: android

I have 4-5 emails acounts for work personal and school.

iOS simply displays a list of these apps, while Android doesn't. Is there an email app on Android that does this?

[image]

EDIT: I tried the Gmail, the k9-mail and I believe Outlook mail application.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [K-9 Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-9_Mail):

[image: K-9 Mail]

The "Unified Inbox" corresponds to your "All Inboxes", the 3 accounts at the bottom are 3 different mail accounts. I'm using this app for years and am quite happy with it. You can find it [at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) as well as [at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.fsck.k9/).

Comment: I should have posted this in the question, but I have eliminated this app quite a long time ago because it doesn't nest replies.  https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/issues/763

Comment: Well, always put such things in your question. Sorry for that then, but my crystal ball is out for maintenance currently ;) I still leave my answer here as it might be helpful for others. // and yeah, those long-standing issues. There's one of mine as well opened more than a year ago. But mine is just a minor annoyance (for me, replace minor with medium)…